# Convert text to Google doc presentation

Tags: api, google-docs

I'm looking for a way to convert text/xml/json (whatever) to a Google doc. The Googles docs api only allows you to create new presentations or upload presentations, not to edit the content of those presentations. I imagine a library or api which converts text to a powerpoint could be a major part of the process.